# Twisted Nematic liquid crystal: extent of degradation due to DC drive?

Tags: material-science, optical-materials

It is commonly accepted wisdom that a Twisted Nematic LCD must always be driven using AC instead of DC, because DC will supposedly denature the LC. I have two questions:

1. Does this effect only happen at typical drive voltages of 8V ~ 9V?  If the LCD is driven with a lower voltage, around 3V, is the degradation not as bad?
2. At 3V, how many hours does it take to degrade the LC? I've run a test for 500 hours with no bad effects.

Thanks!